# Can't install SQL Server 2008 R2 management tool (complete)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on my workstation. I’m in the process of learning Entity Framework, and wanted to use the Management Studio Profiler to help understand the SQL commands generated by EF.

Since the Express version does not include the Profiler, I installed SQL Server 2008-R2 Developer side-by-side with Express. The installation went perfectly and I had no problem adding my databases to the full Server installation.

The problem is that Management Studio – Complete was not installed with the full SQL Server so I still don’t have access to the profiler. I re-ran the installer so I could install the Complete version, but it is greyed out and I cannot select it for installation.

Can someone help me get Management Studio – Complete installed?

If I have to uninstall the Express version, will that hurt anything (I have VS2010 Ultimate installed as well)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve the problem I uninstalled SQL express and the Basic version of Server Management Studio.

Uninstalling SQL Express is not intuitive as it does not appear as a separate item in the “Programs and Features” window.

To uninstall it, I right-clicked on “Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)” and selected Uninstall/Change”.  This opened a dialog, from which I selected ‘Remove’. I navigated though the process until I arrived at a screen which allowed me to elect to remove the Express version (all items with 'Express' in the name). I also elected to remove Management Studio Basic.

After SQL Server Express and Management Studio Basic were uninstalled, I started the SQL Server 2008 R2 installer; this time I was able to select Management Studio Complete for installation.

The installation process executed normally; when it finished the Complete version of Management Studio was available and I was able to execute the Profiler.

Uninstalling SQL Server Express appears to have done no harm to my system; I was able to modify the Server Explorer data connection in VS2010 to connect to my database in the full version of SQL Explorer.

This process outlined above worked for me; YMMV.

Answer (score 49):

I ran into this and had the hardest time getting the Management Tools - Complete to install.  I finally got it working by running the upgrade.  Even though it was already Enterprise edition with nothing obvious to upgrade I went through the update wizard.  After that I was able to do the install of the complete tools.

Steps:

Run the installer -> Maintenance -> Edition Upgrade -> follow the wizard.

Then -> Run the installer -> Installation -> New SQL Server stand-alone ... -> ... "Add features to existing install" -> Management Tools - Complete.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to install instance features, while SQL Management Studio is a Shared feature.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of installing SQL Management Studio is to install another instance using SQL With Tools or the Advance Services issue. Do not look into another instance that is already installed.