# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express: Management Tools Missing from Feature Selection

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am trying to install `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` with the `SQL Server Management Studio`.

However, the Management Tools feature does not seem to be selectable.  The screen-shot below shows which Features are available for me to select:

[image]

I have made sure that the `SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects` was installed!

[image]

I have tried both answered methods at [Can't install SQL Server 2008 R2 management tool (complete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216482/cant-install-sql-server-2008-r2-management-tool-complete) and they both do not seem to work for me, I still do not see Management Tools.  Upgrading the Edition under the Maintenance section and Uninstalling/Re-installing the `SQL Server` had no additional effects.  The files I am trying to work with to get this to work are:

`SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` - This is Service Pack 3

`SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` - The file name fooled me, since **there is no management studio feature selection**!

The question is, why does Microsoft makes it so difficult?

I am using a Windows 7, 64-bit machine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: since the Express edition is artificially limited to using only 1 GB of RAM anyway, I don't see any benefit in using the **64-bit** version..... I personally always use the 32-bit version - even on a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should separately download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express from Microsoft at
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593

Comment: Please note that the file listed in my post "SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe" is the same file that you have suggested to download.  It does not show the Management Tools in the Feature Selection.

Answer (score 0):

SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe contains everything and is the best choice for new installs.